# making *.world file in gazebo package

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, world, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,how can i do to make a .world file?
i read all existing .world file, but i need something else for learning that.

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11949/making-*.world-file-in-gazebo-package/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any tutorials specifically, but the gazebo_worlds package contains some pretty useful examples. I just stumbled across the test_friction.world, and that seems to have a lot of useful models for me to learn from.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0